# is sufficient cohesion equivalent to the connectedness of subobject classifier?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory

I'm following Lawvere article [Axiomatic Cohesion](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/19/3/19-03.pdf).
He states (Proposition VI.4) that sufficient cohesion is equivalent to the connectedness of subject classifier, but I can't follow the proof. I can't see why the connectedness of injective objects implies the existence of an action of the subobject classifier (as a monoid); and the converse the existence of such action implies the connectedness of an injective object.

Or there is another way to prove this fact?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The subobject classifier _always_ acts on the partial map representor.

Comment: Note that the proposition says that sufficient cohesion is equivalent to the connectedness of the subobject classifier _with the background hypothesis that the topos is a "topos of cohesion"_.

Comment: In fact whole cohesion is not needed, as Menni pointed out in [Sufficient Cohesion over atomic toposes](https://e9e1eff6-a-62cb3a1a-s-sites.googlegroups.com/site/matiasmenni/SufCohesion12.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7cqxJKk67FymcWWUtjiF_80KU4by2uTIshZVVfGdnO8jWIt3_PdLXRQDgzRqlmMW_7ksRwo5h6V7SMB2O6tRUT_hyr20tcY_d25EnSE7M8XOgDxmDf1GVAywyVtI-Dt-eIYSd40w4R-vLt5NVfRaad-hJ9ofnDaVzxYob9g8BOtNUQB_2waN_X_Kk41feOcbmtP81EgQSguPdSBu4FRv6rKFHYlxAA%3D%3D&attredirects=0) continuity axiom is not needed. The proposition needs only a pre-cohesive $$p:\mathcal{E}\to\mathcal{S}$$

Comment: I see you are right Zhen Li, but what I can't do is use this action to prove the connexity of the exponential mentioned in Lawvere's article.